# Calling Private Subroutine in Visual Studio to Enable various Radio Boxes

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm very new to programming Visual Basic. I'm working Visual Studio 2015. I am developing an Apartment Configuration program for my class. The instructions require that I enable or disable certain Radio Button options depending on prior selections that are made in the program.

Specifically, the direction is:

- if the option 'Single Apartment' is selected, then only enable the Radio Button Option for a 'One Full Bath'
- if the option 'One Bedroom Apartment' OR 'One Bedroom Plus Den Apartment' is selected, then enable the Radio Button Options for 'One Full Bath' and 'One and a half Bath'
- if the option for Two Bedroom Apartment is selected, then enable the Radio Button Options for 'One and a half Bath' OR 'Two Full Bath'

Visually, the interface looks likes this:
[image]

I have written the following Private Subroutine, the expectation for which is that it would ENABLE or DISABLE various Bathroom based on the Bedroom option selected. However, my code doesn't seem to invoke this routine when I toggle through various Room Size Options.

```
Private Sub EnableBathOptions()
    If rdoBdrmSingle.Checked = True Then
        rdoBthrmOneFull.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmOneonehalf.Enabled = False
        rdoBthrmTwoFull.Enabled = False
    ElseIf rdoOneBdr.Checked = True Then
        rdoBthrmOneFull.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmOneonehalf.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmTwoFull.Enabled = False
    ElseIf rdoOneBdrandDen.Checked = True Then
        rdoBthrmOneFull.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmOneonehalf.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmTwoFull.Enabled = False
    Else
        rdoBthrmOneFull.Enabled = False
        rdoBthrmOneonehalf.Enabled = True
        rdoBthrmTwoFull.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

How should I call/reference this Subroutine in body of my code so that it variably enables or disables bathroom options based on the Bedroom selected?

I have a groupBox called grpBedrooms. Do I call it within that Sub?

```
Private Sub grpBedrooms_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grpBedrooms.Enter
    EnableBathOptions()
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the event that is being handled as your current one is running on the Enter event of the groupbox. If I understand your requirements correctly, you actually need this to run on the `CheckChanged` event of `rdoBdrmSingle`, `rdoOneBdr` and `rdoOneBdrandDen`

```
Private Sub HideControls(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TheNameofYourRadioButtonHere.CheckedChanged
    EnableBathOptions()
End Sub
```

You would need to do the above for `rdoBdrmSingle`, `rdoOneBdr` and `rdoOneBdrandDen` which would mean that each time one of them is changed, the `HideControls` Sub will run.

It may also be worth doing away with `EnableBathOptions` all together and just putting the relevant logic in the relevant event handler

Comment: Thank you for your guidance!